# Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:2.0.40

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dependencies, azure-cognitive-services, emotion

I am trying to use microsoft.projectoxford:emotion in my Android App and when I try to add dependency 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:2.0.40' in my build.gradle in shows the subject error.

```
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:2.0.40'
```

}

Comment: I am working with Android Studio 3.1.1,  Android 8.1 (Oreo) ,Android SDK Platform 27.

Comment: where did you get this version number? in maven, the latest I see is 1.0.355.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.projectoxford/emotion

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Emotion/

Comment: here i got that number

Comment: This is .NET dependency which you cannot download/use without some custom setup. Do you have to use .NET dependency?

Comment: no actually I am new to android and I am trying to learn this tech,

Comment: I need to use this in my Android App

Comment: NuGet package versions and Android package versions are not in sync.

Comment: Also, I should add that the Emotion API is being sunset.  The functionality has been absorbed in to the Face API (Maven version is 1.4.3 as of right now.)

Comment: Thanks @Emma and #cthrash I just successfully sync my project with compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'